# Is it possible to replace values in row to values from the same table by the reference in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

There is a table that contains values that are used in formulas. There are simple variables, that do not contain any expression, and also there are some variables that combined from simple variables into formula. I need to figure out if is it possible to do a SELECT query to get a readable formula based on aliases it contains. Each of these aliases could be used in other formulas.

Let's say that there are two tables:

ITEM TABLE

| ID | Name | FORMULA_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Item name 1 | f_3 |
| 2 | Item name 2 | f_26 |

FORMULA TABLE

| ID | EXPRESSION | ALIASE | NAME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| f_1 | null | var_100 | Ticket |
| f_2 | null | var_200 | Amount |
| f_3 | var_100 * var_200 | var_300 | Some description |

So is there any chance to query, with result like:

| ITEM_NAME | READABLE_EXPRESSION |
| --- | --- |
| Item name 1 | Ticket * Amount |

Comment: Not directly as there is no obvious way for Oracle to parse the expression "var_100 * var_200". You would probably have to code something, for example in PL/SQL. With enough work on your part, it can certainly be done.

Comment: @ewramner, unfortunately I haven't got a great experience with PL/SQL... I've already found that there could be written some function using PL/SQL. It only remains for me to learn it :)

Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
with items(ID,Name,Formula_Id) AS (
    select 1, 'Item name 1', 'f_3' from dual union all
    select 2, 'Item name 2', 'f_26' from dual
),
formulas (ID, EXPRESSION, ALIAS, NAME) as (
    select 'f_1', null, 'var_100', 'Ticket' from dual union all
    select 'f_2', null, 'var_200', 'Amount' from dual union all
    select 'f_3', 'var_100 * var_200', 'var_300', 'Some description' from dual 
),
rnformulas (id, EXPRESSION, ALIAS, NAME, rn) as (
    select fm.*, row_number() over(order by id) as rn from formulas fm
),
recsubstitute( lvl, item_id, rn, expression ) as (
    select 1, it.id, 0, fm.expression
    from items it
    join rnformulas fm on it.formula_id = fm.id
    
    union all
    select lvl+1, item_id, fm.rn, replace(r.expression, fm.alias, fm.name)
    from recsubstitute r
    join rnformulas fm on instr(r.expression, fm.alias) > 0 and fm.rn > r.rn
)
select item_id, expression from (
    select item_id, expression, row_number() over(partition by item_id order by lvl desc, rn asc) as rn   
    from recsubstitute 
)
where rn = 1
;

       ITEM_ID EXPRESSION                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    ---------- ------------------------------------------------------------            
1 Ticket * Amount
```

Note that it's far to be bullet proof against all situations, especially recursion in the aliases.

Answer (score 0):

Some improvement with another set of data:

```
with items(ID,Name,Formula_Id) AS (
    select 1, 'Item name 1', 'f_3' from dual union all
    select 2, 'Item name 2', 'f_4' from dual
),
formulas (ID, EXPRESSION, ALIAS, NAME) as (
    select 'f_1', null, 'var_100', 'Ticket' from dual union all
    select 'f_2', null, 'var_200', 'Amount' from dual union all
    select 'f_3', 'var_100 * var_200', 'var_300', 'Some description' from dual union all
    select 'f_4', 'var_300', null, 'Other description' from dual 
),
rnformulas (id, EXPRESSION, ALIAS, NAME, rn) as (
    select fm.*, row_number() over(order by id) as rn from formulas fm
),
recsubstitute( lvl, item_id, rn, expression ) as (
    select 1, it.id, 0, fm.expression
    from items it
    join rnformulas fm on it.formula_id = fm.id
    
    union all
    select lvl+1, item_id, fm.rn, replace(r.expression, fm.alias, nvl(fm.expression,fm.name))
    from recsubstitute r
    join rnformulas fm on instr(r.expression, fm.alias) > 0 
)
select item_id, expression from (
    select item_id, expression, row_number() over(partition by item_id order by lvl desc, rn asc) as rn   
    from recsubstitute 
)
where rn = 1
;

1   Ticket * Amount
2   Ticket * Amount
```

Answer (score 0):

1. With sample data create CTE (calc_data) for modeling

```sql
WITH
    items (ITEM_ID, ITEM_NAME, FORMULA_ID) AS
        (
            Select 1,   'Item name 1',  'f_3' From Dual Union All
            Select 2,   'Item name 2',  'f_26' From Dual
        ),
    formulas (FORMULA_ID, EXPRESSION, ALIAS, ELEMENT_NAME) AS
        (
            Select 'f_1',   null,               'var_100',  'Ticket' From Dual Union All
            Select 'f_2',   null,               'var_200',  'Amount' From Dual Union All
            Select 'f_3',   'var_100 * var_200',    'var_300',  'Some description' From Dual
        ),
  calc_data AS
    (   SELECT  e.ITEM_NAME, e.FORMULA_ID, e.FORMULA, e.X, e.OPERAND, e.Y,  
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition By e.ITEM_NAME Order By e.FORMULA_ID) "RN", f.ELEMENT_NAME 
        FROM(   Select  CAST('.' as VARCHAR2(32)) "FORMULA", i.ITEM_NAME, f.FORMULA_ID,
                    SubStr(Replace(f.EXPRESSION, ' ', ''), 1, InStr(Replace(f.EXPRESSION, ' ', ''), '*') - 1) "X",
                    CASE 
                        WHEN InStr(f.EXPRESSION, '+') > 0 THEN '+'
                        WHEN InStr(f.EXPRESSION, '-') > 0 THEN '-'
                        WHEN InStr(f.EXPRESSION, '*') > 0 THEN '*'
                        WHEN InStr(f.EXPRESSION, '/') > 0 THEN '/'
                    END "OPERAND",
                    --
                    SubStr(Replace(f.EXPRESSION, ' ', ''), InStr(Replace(f.EXPRESSION, ' ', ''), '*') + 1) "Y"
                From    formulas f
                Inner Join items i  ON(f.FORMULA_ID = i.FORMULA_ID)
            ) e
        Inner Join formulas f ON(f.FORMULA_ID <> e.FORMULA_ID)
    )
```

2. **Main SQL with MODEL clause**

```sql
SELECT  ITEM_NAME, FORMULA
FROM    (   SELECT  * 
            FROM calc_data
            MODEL
                PARTITION BY    (ITEM_NAME)
                DIMENSION BY    (RN)
                MEASURES        (X, OPERAND, Y, FORMULA, ELEMENT_NAME)
                RULES       (  FORMULA[1] = ELEMENT_NAME[1] || ' ' || OPERAND[1] || ' ' || ELEMENT_NAME[2] )
        )
WHERE RN = 1
```

R e s u l t :

| ITEM_NAME | FORMULA |
| --- | --- |
| Item name 1 | Amount * Ticket |

*Just as an option...

The same result without any analytic functions, pseudo columns, unions, etc... - just selecting over and over and over. Not readable, though...*

```sql
Select
    i.ITEM_NAME,
    REPLACE(  REPLACE(  (Select EXPRESSION From formulas Where FORMULA_ID = f.FORMULA_ID), 
                  (Select Min(ALIAS) From formulas Where FORMULA_ID <> f.FORMULA_ID),
                  (Select ELEMENT_NAME From formulas Where FORMULA_ID <> f.FORMULA_ID And ALIAS = (Select Min(ALIAS) From formulas Where FORMULA_ID <> f.FORMULA_ID) )
               )   ||
              REPLACE(  (Select EXPRESSION From formulas Where FORMULA_ID = f.FORMULA_ID), 
                        (Select Max(ALIAS) From formulas Where FORMULA_ID <> f.FORMULA_ID), 
                        (Select ELEMENT_NAME From formulas Where FORMULA_ID <> f.FORMULA_ID And ALIAS = (Select Max(ALIAS) From formulas Where FORMULA_ID <> f.FORMULA_ID) )  
              ), 
              (SELECT Max(ALIAS) From formulas Where FORMULA_ID <> f.FORMULA_ID  ) || (Select Min(ALIAS) From formulas Where FORMULA_ID <> f.FORMULA_ID) || 
                              SubStr(f.EXPRESSION, InStr(f.EXPRESSION, ' ', 1, 1), (InStr(f.EXPRESSION, ' ', 1, 2) - InStr(f.EXPRESSION, ' ', 1, 1)) + 1 ), ''
    ) "FORMULA"
From
    formulas f
Left Join
    items i ON(i.FORMULA_ID = f.FORMULA_ID)
Where i.ITEM_NAME Is Not Null
```

Answer (score 0):

Split the space-delimited formulas into rows. Join the expression parts to the aliases and replace the alias with the name. Join this to the item_table using LISTAGG to concatenate the rows back into a single column.

```
WITH formula_split AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT ft.id
          ,level                                        lvl
          ,regexp_substr(ft.expression,'[^ ]+',1,level) expression_part
      FROM formula_table ft
    CONNECT BY ( ft.id = ft.id
       AND level <= length(ft.expression) - length(replace(ft.expression,' ')) + 1 ) START WITH ft.expression IS NOT NULL
),readable_tbl AS (
    SELECT ft.id
          ,ft.lvl
          ,replace(ft.expression_part,ftn1.aliase,ftn1.name) readable_expression
      FROM formula_split ft
      LEFT JOIN formula_table  ftn1 ON ( ft.expression_part = ftn1.aliase )
)
SELECT it.name item_name
      ,LISTAGG(readable_expression,' ') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY lvl) readable_expression
  FROM item_table it
  JOIN readable_tbl rt ON ( it.formula_id = rt.id )
 GROUP BY it.name
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your answers!

I've decided to create a pl/sql function, just to modify a formula to readable row. So the function just looks for variables using regex, and uses indexes to replace every variable with a name.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION READABLE_EXPRESSION(inExpression IN VARCHAR2)
    RETURN VARCHAR2
    IS
    matchesCount       INTEGER;
    toReplace          VARCHAR2(32767);
    readableExpression VARCHAR2(32767);
    selectString       VARCHAR2(32767);
BEGIN
    matchesCount := REGEXP_COUNT(inExpression, '(var_)(.*?)');

    IF matchesCount IS NOT NULL AND matchesCount > 0 THEN
        readableExpression := inExpression;

        FOR i in 1..matchesCount
            LOOP
                toReplace := substr(inExpression, REGEXP_INSTR(inExpression, '(var_)(.*?)', 1, i, 0),
                                    REGEXP_INSTR(inExpression, '(var_)(.*?)', 1, i, 1) -
                                    REGEXP_INSTR(inExpression, '(var_)(.*?)', 1, i, 0)
                    );

                SELECT DISTINCT F.NAME
                INTO selectString
                FROM FORMULA F
                WHERE F.ALIASE = toReplace FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;

                readableExpression := REPLACE(readableExpression,
                                              toReplace,
                                              selectString
                    );
            end loop;
    end if;
    return readableExpression;
END;
```

So such function returns 1 result row with replaced values for 1 input row with FORMULA. All you need to do is join the ITEM and FORMULA tables in the SELECT.

```
SELECT item.name, READABLE_EXPRESSION(formula.expression) 
FROM item
JOIN formula ON item.formula_id = formula.id;
```

Please note that the tables are fictitious so as not to reveal the actual data structure, so there might be some inaccuracies. But the general idea should be clear.