Use recursive query to replace formula in Oracle
I have below two tables in Oracle.
Create table Calc(CALC_CD VARCHAR(10), FORMULA1 VARCHAR(200), FORMULA2 VARCHAR(200), FORMULA3 VARCHAR(200), FORMULA4 VARCHAR(200));
Create table UnitData(UnitNumber VARCHAR(100), CALC_CD VARCHAR(10), GRP_CD VARCHAR(100), GRP_AMT DECIMAL);

insert into Calc VALUES('M10', 'SI01/VI01', 'SI02/VI02', 'Part1 * 0.3', 'Part2 + Part3');
    
insert into UnitData VALUES ('111E', 'M10', 'SI01', 233.23);
insert into UnitData VALUES ('111E', 'M10', 'VI01', 4.98);
insert into UnitData VALUES ('111E', 'M10', 'SI02', 233.23);
insert into UnitData VALUES ('111E', 'M10', 'VI02', 4.98);
insert into UnitData VALUES ('112E', 'M10', 'SI01', 133.23);
insert into UnitData VALUES ('112E', 'M10', 'VI01', 3.98);
insert into UnitData VALUES ('112E', 'M10', 'SI02', 133.23);
insert into UnitData VALUES ('112E', 'M10', 'VI02', 3.98);

And third result table which as below: 

Create table Calc_Result(UnitNumber VARCHAR(100), CALC_CD VARCHAR(10), Formula1 VARCHAR(200), Formula2 VARCHAR(200), Formula3 VARCHAR(200), Formula4 VARCHAR(200), FORMULA_RESULT DECIMAL)

Result would look like this:
UnitNumber | Calc_CD | Formula1    | Formula2    | Formula3       | Formula4         | Formula_Result
111E       | M10     | 233.23/4.98 | 233.23/4.98 | 46.83 * 0.3    | 14.05 + 46.83    | 60.88 

Right now, I do all this calculation using multiple cursors. Outer cursor loops through each Unit, couple of inner cursor first replaces group code with actual amounts and then calculate result for each formula and feed to the next one. This is a short version of rather complex solution, where I would have up-to 10 Formula. Is there any way to use the recursive query replace all occurrence of the "SI*" & "VI*" values in all formula with their actual amount? UnitData is very large table with over 32M records & as of now it takes over 5 hours to complete this task. I am looking to replace few cursors to speed up the process.
Here is a link for db fiddle with sample data: DB_Fiddle

Here you have a question of the same "family" or problematic:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74851641/is-it-possible-to-replace-values-in-row-to-values-from-the-same-table-by-the-ref

If you have the formula formula1 = 'A + B', formula2 = 'C + D' and formula3 = 'Part1 * Part2 do you expect the result to be A + B * C + D which using standard arithmetic rules would be the same as A + (B * C) + D, or do expect to evaluate the parts first so would expect (A + B) * (C + D)?

@MT0 expectation was to calculate each formula in sequence and result is result of final formula.

Lets write a parser in SQL ... (adapting my answer to a similar question to handle more than single-character terms and literal terms)

Implement the shunting yard algorithm as a recursive sub-query; and then
Take the reverse polish output from the shunting yard and use it to calculate the value.

WITH FUNCTION is_operator(term VARCHAR2)
  RETURN NUMBER
  IS
  BEGIN
    RETURN CASE
           WHEN term IS NULL THEN NULL
           WHEN term IN ('+ ', '- ', '/ ', '* ', '^ ') THEN 1
           ELSE 0
           END;
  END;
FUNCTION priority(operator VARCHAR2)
  RETURN NUMBER
  IS
  BEGIN
    RETURN CASE operator
           WHEN '+ ' THEN 1
           WHEN '- ' THEN 1
           WHEN '/ ' THEN 2
           WHEN '* ' THEN 2
           WHEN '^ ' THEN 3
           END;
  END;
calc1 (calc_cd, formula2, formula3, formula4) AS (
  SELECT calc_cd,
         REPLACE(formula2, 'Part1', '('||formula1||')'),
         REPLACE(formula3, 'Part1', '('||formula1||')'),
         REPLACE(formula4, 'Part1', '('||formula1||')')
  FROM   calc
),
calc2 (calc_cd, formula3, formula4) AS (
  SELECT calc_cd,
         REPLACE(formula3, 'Part2', '('||formula2||')'),
         REPLACE(formula4, 'Part2', '('||formula2||')')
  FROM   calc1
),
calc3 (calc_cd, formula) AS (
  SELECT calc_cd,
         REPLACE(formula4, 'Part3', '('||formula3||')')
  FROM   calc2
),
shunting_yard (calc_cd, formula, input, stack, output) AS (
  SELECT calc_cd,
         formula,
         TRIM(
           REPLACE(
             REGEXP_REPLACE(
               formula,
               '\s*([()^*/+-])\s*',
               ' \1 '
             ),
             '  ',
             ' '
           )
         ) || ' ',
         CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR2(4000)),
         CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR2(4000))
  FROM   calc3
UNION ALL
  SELECT calc_cd,
         formula,
         CASE
         WHEN (f_term = ') ' AND s_term != '( ')
         THEN input
         WHEN f_term IN ('( ', ') ')
         OR   is_operator(f_term) = 0
         OR   stack IS NULL
         OR   s_term = '( '
         OR   priority(s_term) < priority(f_term)
         THEN SUBSTR(input, INSTR(input, ' ') + 1)
         ELSE input
         END,
         CASE
         WHEN f_term = '( '
         THEN f_term || stack
         WHEN f_term = ') '
         THEN SUBSTR(stack, INSTR(stack, ' ') + 1)
         WHEN is_operator(f_term) = 0
         THEN stack
         WHEN stack IS NULL
         OR   s_term = '( '
         OR   priority(s_term) < priority(f_term)
         THEN f_term || stack
         ELSE SUBSTR(stack, INSTR(stack, ' ') + 1)
         END,
         CASE
         WHEN f_term = '( '
         OR   (f_term = ') ' AND s_term = '( ')
         THEN output
         WHEN f_term = ') ' AND s_term != '( '
         THEN output || s_term
         WHEN is_operator(f_term) = 0
         THEN output || f_term
         WHEN stack IS NULL
         OR   s_term = '( '
         OR   priority(s_term) < priority(f_term)
         THEN output
         ELSE output || s_term
         END
  FROM   shunting_yard
         CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
           SELECT SUBSTR(input, 1, INSTR(input, ' '))
                    AS f_term,
                  SUBSTR(stack, 1, INSTR(stack, ' '))
                    AS s_term
           FROM   DUAL
         )
)
SEARCH DEPTH FIRST BY calc_cd, input SET order_id
CYCLE calc_cd, input, stack, output SET done TO 1 DEFAULT 0,
reverse_polish (unitnumber, calc_cd, formula, input, stack) AS (
  SELECT CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR2(100)),
         calc_cd,
         formula,
         output,
         CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR2(4000))
  FROM   shunting_yard
  WHERE  done = 1
UNION ALL
  SELECT t.unitnumber,
         r.calc_cd,
         r.formula,
         SUBSTR(r.input, INSTR(r.input, ' ', 1, 1) + 1),
         CASE t.f_term
         WHEN '+'
         THEN TO_CHAR(t.s_term2 + t.s_term1) || ' ' || t.s_tail
         WHEN '-'
         THEN TO_CHAR(t.s_term2 - t.s_term1) || ' ' || t.s_tail
         WHEN '*'
         THEN TO_CHAR(t.s_term2 * t.s_term1) || ' ' || t.s_tail
         WHEN '/'
         THEN TO_CHAR(t.s_term2 / t.s_term1) || ' ' || t.s_tail
         WHEN '^'
         THEN TO_CHAR(POWER(t.s_term2, t.s_term1)) || ' ' || t.s_tail
         ELSE COALESCE(TO_CHAR(t.value), t.f_term) || ' ' || r.stack
         END
  FROM   reverse_polish r
         CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
           SELECT SUBSTR(r.input, 1, INSTR(r.input, ' ') - 1) AS f_term,
                  TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(r.stack, 1, INSTR(r.stack, ' ') - 1)) AS s_term1,
                  TO_NUMBER(
                    CASE 
                    WHEN INSTR(r.stack, ' ', 1, 2) > 0
                    THEN TO_NUMBER(
                           SUBSTR(
                             r.stack,
                             INSTR(r.stack, ' ', 1, 1) + 1,
                             INSTR(r.stack, ' ', 1, 2) - INSTR(r.stack, ' ', 1, 1) - 1
                           )
                         )
                    END
                  ) AS s_term2,
                  SUBSTR(r.stack, INSTR(r.stack, ' ', 1, 2) + 1) AS s_tail,
                  COALESCE(u.unitnumber, r.unitnumber) AS unitnumber,
                  u.grp_amt AS value
           FROM   DUAL
                  LEFT OUTER JOIN unitdata u
                  ON     (r.unitnumber IS NULL OR r.unitnumber = u.unitnumber)
                     AND r.calc_cd = u.calc_cd
                     AND SUBSTR(r.input, 1, INSTR(r.input, ' ') - 1) = u.grp_cd
         ) t
  WHERE  r.input IS NOT NULL
)
SEARCH DEPTH FIRST BY unitnumber, calc_cd, input SET order_id
CYCLE unitnumber, calc_cd, input, stack SET done TO 1 DEFAULT 0
SELECT unitnumber,
       calc_cd,
       formula,
       TO_NUMBER(stack) AS value
FROM   reverse_polish
WHERE  input IS NULL;

Which, for the sample data:
Create table Calc(
  CALC_CD  VARCHAR2(10),
  FORMULA1 VARCHAR2(200),
  FORMULA2 VARCHAR2(200),
  FORMULA3 VARCHAR2(200),
  FORMULA4 VARCHAR2(200)
);

Create table UnitData(
  UnitNumber VARCHAR2(100),
  CALC_CD    VARCHAR2(10),
  GRP_CD     VARCHAR2(100),
  GRP_AMT    NUMBER
);

insert into Calc (calc_cd, formula1, formula2, formula3, formula4)
  SELECT 'M10', 'SI01/VI01', 'SI02/VI02', 'Part1 * 0.3', 'Part2 + Part3' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'M10', 'SI01', 'VI02', 'Part1', 'Part3 ^ Part2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'M10', 'SI01 - VI01', 'SI02 + VI02', 'Part1 * 0.3 + 2', 'Part2 / Part3' FROM DUAL;

insert into UnitData (unitnumber, calc_cd, grp_cd, grp_amt)
  select '111E', 'M10', 'SI01', 233.23 from dual union
  select '111E', 'M10', 'VI01',   4.98 from dual union
  select '111E', 'M10', 'SI02', 233.23 from dual union
  select '111E', 'M10', 'VI02',   4.98 from dual union
  select '112E', 'M10', 'SI01', 133.23 from dual union
  select '112E', 'M10', 'VI01',   3.98 from dual union
  select '112E', 'M10', 'SI02', 133.23 from dual union
  select '112E', 'M10', 'VI02',   3.98 from dual

Outputs:



UNITNUMBER
CALC_CD
FORMULA
VALUE




111E
M10
((SI01)) ^ (VI02)
618822894936.360378888509577862392629892


112E
M10
((SI01)) ^ (VI02)
285703835.699108676302209925319691931182


111E
M10
(SI02 + VI02) / ((SI01 - VI01) * 0.3 + 2)
3.38006385242993969492727917701312522171


112E
M10
(SI02 + VI02) / ((SI01 - VI01) * 0.3 + 2)
3.36505211526670754138565297363580625383


111E
M10
(SI02/VI02) + ((SI01/VI01) * 0.3)
60.8833333333333333333333333333333333333


112E
M10
(SI02/VI02) + ((SI01/VI01) * 0.3)
43.5173366834170854271356783919597989949



Note: The calc table only has a calc_cd column and does not correlate to unitdata on any particular unitnumber so you will get output for both matching unitnumbers.
fiddle

Thank you very much for a detailed query. I was not aware of the shunting-yard algo. I will read. Is it also able to output values in each formula, for instance, 233.23/4.98  in Formula1

@Visha "Is it also able to output values in each formula" see my comment on the question because evaluating the formulae individually may give you the wrong answer if you are expecting to use standard arithmetic rules. If you did want to do it then it is theoretically possible but you would need to parse each formula using a query like in the answer and repeating that 4 times would result in a monster of a query .... definitely possible but I'm not going to attempt to write it (you are trying to do something that SQL was not intended to solve).
